# concatenating strings in C without the use of library functions

Tags: c, string, concatenation

I need to write a simple program (no fancy pointer stuff, no library functions. It's for educational purposes) that reads the first and second names from a user and prints them out in a single line separated by a space. I am not getting the result and I am not sure why:

```
# include <stdio.h>
//the program loosely simulates the behaviour of strcpy
main(){
    char fname[16], sname[16], cat[31];
    int i, j;
    printf("Please enter your first name: ");
    scanf("%s", fname);
    printf("Please enter your second name: ");
    scanf("%s", sname);

    for (i=0; fname[i] != '\0'; cat[i++] = fname[i++])
        ;

    cat[i+1] = ' '; //adds a space between the tokens

    for (j=i+1; sname[j] != '\0'; cat[j++] = sname[j++])
        ;   

    printf("The final result is:\n%s", cat);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have `j=i+1`, and then use `sname[j++]` --- you're accessing `sname` out of bounds, plus some UB (see the next post) and so on. I spot 3 or so errors here, at least.

Comment: `cat[i++] = fname[i++]` is probably not going to do what you expect. `cat[i] = fname[i], i++` is safer.

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: Or he can just put the assignment in the (currently empty) body of the `for` loop, where it belongs.

Comment: @TimČas Yes, that would make more sense

Comment: OT: [Never use `%s` in `scanf` without a field width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems. First, since `cat` has to be big enough to hold the first two strings **and** a space between them, it should be declared `cat[32]` -- 15 characters of first name, 15 characters of surname, 1 space, and 1 trailing null byte.

You're putting the space between the words in the wrong place. The first loop left `i` holding the next position in `cat`, so it should be:

```
cat[i] = ' ';
```

Next, your array indexes in the second loop are incorrect. The positions in `cat` are correct, because they start from where you left off the previous loop. But you need to start from `0` in `sname`. So this loop should be:

```
for (j = i+1, k = 0; sname[k] != 0; cat[j++] = sname[k++])
    ;
```

Finally, after concatenating the two strings, you need to append a null byte to the result, to indicate the end.

```
cat[j] = 0;
```

Another problem is that you're incrementing `i` twice each time through the first loop, since you use `cat[i++] = fname[i++]`. Each of those `i++` will increment the variable. You need to separate the assignment from the increments:

```
for (i=0; fname[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    cat[i] = fname[i];
}
```

Here's a final version of the script that works:

```
# include <stdio.h>
//the program loosely simulates the behaviour of strcpy

int main() {
    char fname[16], sname[16], cat[32];
    int i, j, k;
    printf("Please enter your first name: ");
    scanf("%s", fname);
    printf("Please enter your second name: ");
    scanf("%s", sname);

    for (i=0; fname[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        cat[i] = fname[i];
    }

    cat[i] = ' ';

    for (j = i+1, k = 0; sname[k] != 0; cat[j++] = sname[k++]) {
    }

    cat[j] = 0;

    printf("The final result is: %s\n", cat);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean the `cat` should be declared with `32` characters, right? Because it already contains `31` cells. Your analysis seems very plausibe, however when I run your corrected version, I get a two page error and the program doesn't even compile.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. What error are you getting?

Comment: It complains about many things and is not clear where it went wrong. It says for example: `expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'fname'` and somewhere else it says `error: invalid initializer`. Here is the corrected code: http://paste.ofcode.org/38aK7vqBuYUMirpbbNKGpZ6

Comment: Your code needs to be in the `main()` function. You can't run code outside a function in C.

Comment: Oh crap. Sorry. Yeah, I got distracted. typo. (My original program included the main function of course) Now that I correct it, it gives back the exact same result as before!! for example if I give `John` and `Doe` as fname and sname I get some weird output like `J0h`

Answer (score 0):

I realize you set yourself a challenge to try to learn how to do something specific (and I see you are making progress towards your goal). But I always like to keep in mind there are lots of ways to get the job done -- especially in C. You know you could just do this with `printf`, right?

```
char fname[16], sname[16];
int i, j;
printf("Please enter your first name: ");
scanf("%s", fname);
printf("Please enter your second name: ");
scanf("%s", sname);

printf("%s %s\n", fname, sname);
```

Comment: Yeah, I am actually supposed to do this using array manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

Watch the index you use :

`cat[i++] = fname[i++]` and `cat[j++] = sname[j++]`

try to increment 'i' and 'j' at the end of your loop :

```
for (i=0; fname[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    cat[i] = fname[i];
// ...
for (j=0; sname[j] != '\0';++j)
    cat[j+i+1] = sname[j];
```